# Highcharts Tootip in wrong location for multiple x axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

I've got a chart with two x axis side-by-side, with one series in each.  When I float over the Series 1 data, I see the tooltip, as expected.  When I float over Series 2 data, it highlights the line, but no tooltip.  However, if I move the cursor to the left at the same height as the data in Series 2 data, but above the Series 1 data, the tooltip shows the Series 2 information, and the Series 2 points are highlighted.  Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/q0gphwx2/5/

Is there a way to correct for this?

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    plotOptions : {
        area : {
            stacking : 'normal',
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Tooltip Hover Anomoly'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Float over Series 2 data, then stay at same height, but over series 1.  '
    },
    xAxis: [{
        width:300,
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },{
        left: 400,
        width: 300,
        offset:0,
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    }

           ],
    yAxis: [{ // Secondary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mm',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }

    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Series 1',
        type: 'line',
        xAxis: 0,
        stack: 0,            
        data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 20, 30],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Series 2',
        type: 'line',
        xAxis: 1,
        stack: 1,
        data: [100, 120, 100, 120, 100, 120, 100, 120, 100, 120, 100, 120],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        }

    }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is known bug, reported to our developers [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3346)

Comment: Based on comments in issue #3346 you reference, and using the 4.1 candidate, this seems to be mostly fixed, (with the exception of the tooltip position, which I can work around).  That will work for me for the time being. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a second axis like that (using widths, left, offset, etc...) just to space out two years seems very problematic.  Instead, use one axis, extend the categories through two sets of months and then start the second series at point 12:

```
   xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec',
                     'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    }],

    series: [{
        name: 'Series 1',
        type: 'line',           
        data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 20, 30],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Series 2',
        type: 'line',
        pointStart: 12, // start this one at 12
        data: [100, 120, 100, 120, 100, 120, 100, 120, 100, 120, 100, 120],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        }

    }]
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0gphwx2/7/).

Comment: My example was to illustrate the problem as simply as possible.  My actual case involves displaying disk usage over time (datetime) on a set of network shares for several agencies.  However, I may be able to use your solution if I can ensure the data is monthly.